# Having trouble using PHP's include statement

Tags: php, apache, lamp

I cant for the life of me get PHP's 'include' statement to work on any files other than files in the same directory as the file using the 'include' statement. When I try to include any file from another directory the whole app breaks and nothing loads.

I dump that script in, say:

> /var/www/html/fooA/testClass.php

and try to include it using:

> /var/www/html/different_than_fooA/include_testClass.php

and the app breaks. However, if I include:

> /html/foo_1.php

in:

> /html/foo_2.php

everything works fine...

I promise this is not a simple syntax issue, I've tried writing it every way possible, using slashes in front, or no slash in front, whole directories and partial directories, IP addresses, even tried loading from other servers. My guess is it has to do with the way PHP or Apache is configured. Almost nothing hits on this matter that I can find floating around the internet, any advice would be great.

```
<?php
    // THIS FILE IS TEST/TEST02.php

    require 'TEST01.php';
    $V = new X();
    $V->Z();
?>
```

Comment: do you get any error message ??

Comment: Page just doesnt load, as soon as I remove the include statment or change it to a path with a class in the same directory the page wil then load

Comment: this is not an error description; enable error reporting or check the server's `error_log`,

Comment: You haven't shown us either the offending code or the error message. All we have is some seemingly irrelevant class. It's quite hard to fix invisible errors. Please show us the necessary information. Thanks

Comment: Sorry had to run code, its an HTTP error 500

Comment: There I changed code to the offending code

Comment: How I write the syntax for the include statement has varied. In this instence I am trying to run it by itsself since the class is in the root dir (/var/www/html) I have though indeed tried include '/var/www/html/TEST01.php' Ive tried the whole HTTP address using the IP.

Comment: @AfterLife you shouldn't ignore my suggestion if you want this question answered... try `require_once()` ...because the `include()` function behaves slightly different: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: A 500 error is a (deliberately) generic crash code which could mean anything. Please check your error_log file as per Martin's suggestion, to find the specific underlying error message. If error logging isn't turned on then please turn it on (you can Google it) and then try again

Comment: P.s. you don't usually include or require files using the IP address or web address.... especially not it they're on the same server. Stick to using file paths. Hopefully once you see the real error it'll be easier to work out what to do about it

Answer (score 1):

You can always use PHP's magic constants and that way you can be sure that it will figure out the correct path for you.

```
/* lets say we have a folder structure like below
 *
 * - FolderA
 *  -- fileA.php
 * - FolderB
 *  -- fileB.php
 */

 // We require fileA.php in fileB.php, here is how we can do it

 require __DIR__.'/../FolderA/fileA.php';
```

Here is the link to documentation. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Answer (score 1):

By default PHP sets the `include_path` as follows:

**On  *nix systems**

```
include_path=".:/php/includes"
```

**On Widows systems**

```
include_path=".;c:\php\includes"
```

You can, and should, override these defaults to suit your environment as it is unlikely that you will have placed all the relevant files in these locations.

> Using a . in the include path allows for relative includes as it means
>   the current directory. However, it is more efficient to explicitly use
>   include './file' than having PHP always check the current directory
>   for every include.

In order to override the default locations use `set_include_path("/path/to/includes/")` etc which then allows a simple call to include the files like this:

```
set_include_path("/path/to/includes/");
include 'class.foobar.php';
require 'functions.php'; // etc
```

If you need to load class files one alternative would be to use the `__autoload` method equivalent and write your own callback to handle loading of files. The original `__autoload` method is deprecated but an improved `spl_autoload` class exists to facillitate this.

The following references `ALIASED_SITE_ROOT` and `ROOT_PATH` which are globally defined constants on my system and point to particular directories so will not be relevant to you and will need editing if you decide to adopt this approach to loading classes.

[More info on "spl_autoload_register"](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php)

```
function autoloader( $classname=false ){

    $included=get_included_files();
    $classname=rtrim( $classname, '.php' );

    $dirs = array(
        '/path/to/includes/',
        ALIASED_SITE_ROOT . '/inc/',
        ALIASED_SITE_ROOT . '/inc/forms/',
        ALIASED_SITE_ROOT . '/inc/lib/',
        ROOT_PATH . '/inc/',
        ROOT_PATH . '/'
    );
    /* add other locations to the above array */
    foreach( $dirs as $dir ) {
        $fullpath = $dir . $classname . '.php';

        if ( file_exists( $fullpath ) ) {
            if( !in_array( $fullpath, $included ) ) {
                require_once( $fullpath );
                clearstatcache();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    set_include_path( $dirs[ 0 ] );
}
spl_autoload_register( 'autoloader' );
```

With the above registered in a common include file when you need to load a class you no longer need to do `require '/path/to/includes/foobar.php';` when you need to work with the file you could simply do:

```
$foo=new foobar(); // no need to use `require` or `include` as it has been autoloaded
```

So the above works well with classes - a consistent naming strategy will help immensely if you adopt this approach! For example, I tend to locate all classes in what is shown above as `ALIASED_SITE_ROOT . '/inc/'` and use a naming convention of `class.foobar.php` so in the autoload function

```
$fullpath = $dir . $classname . '.php';
```

is actually

```
$fullpath = $dir . 'class.' . $classname . '.php';
```

It follows that the class name must match the name given by `$classname`, for example:

```
class foobar{
    public function __construct(){
       /* etc */
    }
}
```